# Usar la clausula OR ( || ) en consultas de tipo Eloquent en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Saludos comunidad tengo una duda y no se como se resuelve...

Como bien sabemos si yo quisiera hacer una consulta que tuviera una clausula OR en SQl seria algo así:

```
Select * tabla where campoA='1' || campoA='2'
```

El asunto es que lo estoy haciendo en Laravel 5.2 usando eloquent y segun la documentacion debo usar el orWhere.

```
$variable=Tabla::orderBy('id')
->where('campoA','=','1')
->orWhere('campoA','=','2')
->get();
```

El problema es que he hecho esto y lo que obtengo no es el resultado esperado, me da otro tipo de resultado, entonces no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, ya que me he guiado por la documentación, de estar mal hecho, cual es la manera correcta de usar esta opción?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me parece que el error se origina al invocar `groupBy()` antes que las clausulas `where()`.

### Solución

La consulta debería tener la siguiente forma:

```php
$variable=Tabla::where('campoA','=','1')
    ->orWhere('campoA','=','2')
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

### Alternativa

Como veo que el valor que buscas se encuentra en un rango, puedes utilizar el método [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) para indicarle un rango de valores para una determinada llave:

```php
$variable=Tabla::whereIn('campoA', ['1','2'])
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

La documentación lo explica mejor:

> #### whereIn / whereNotIn
>
> El método `whereIn` verifica que el valor de una columna dada se
>   encuentre dentro de los valores del arreglo pasado como segundo parámetro:
>
> ```php
> $users = DB::table('users')
>                 ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
>                 ->get();
> ```
>
> El método `whereNotIn` verifica que el valor de una columna dada no se
>   encuentre dentro de los valores del arreglo pasado como segundo parámetro:
>
> ```php
> $users = DB::table('users')
>                 ->whereNotIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
>                 ->get();
> ```

Comment: Gracias, esta solución me dio el resultado buscado, menos código y mas objetiva.

Comment: @joseangarita excelente! Entonces ya puedes marcar la pregunta como resuelta. Buen día.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tu clase que representa la tabla donde debes hacer la consulta se llama tabla puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$variable=  Tabla::where('campoA','1')
    ->orWhere('campoA', '2')
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

En lo anterior puedes omitir el segundo parametro que tenias el `=` ya que es por defecto el tipo de comparacion a usar. Puedes hacerlo de esta otra forma tambien:

```
$variable = DB::table('tu_table')
    ->where('campoA','1')
    ->orWhere('campoA', '2')
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

Verifica que en tu tabla realmente tengas registros con esos valores.

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

Te saludo y te comento que usando Eloquent tu consulta puede quedar del modo siguiente

**CÓDIGO QUE SOLUCIONA LA PREGUNTA**

```
$data = Tabla::select('*')
    ->where('campoA', '=', '1')
    ->orWhere('campoA', '=', 2)
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

> Respetando plenamente el operador de comodín `*` que estas usando para
>   traer todos los datos, perfectamente después de invocar al modelo
>   `Tabla en este caso` haces que acceda al método estático select, por
>   dentro de este mismo le pasas el operador `*` y posteriormente
>   mediante method chaining o encadenamiento de métodos pasas los dos
>   where, primero el principal y luego el que lleva el operador lógico
>   `or` finalmente cierras tu consulta con el método `get();` para que te
>   retorne tus datos

Con lo anterior vas a poder seguir usando Eloquent y te evitas usar Fluent que es el queryBuilder

El método orderBy(), puede tener las siguientes estructuras

```
->orderBy('id');
->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Tabla es el nombre equivalente del modelo que estes usando
2. el método `select()` recibirá el operador comodín `*` o el nombre de las columnas especificas que deseas consultar
3. primero va el método `where`
4. posterior dada la lógica de consulta va el método `orWhere()`

Fuente de consulta

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Para el caso de las consultas con el uso de los distintos métodos `where()`, el siguiente enlace de la dcoumentación oficial te será de utilidad

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Gracias por responder

Comment: @joseangarita de nada espero haber ayudado